# When going back and forth between pages it keeps input value but not text set by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with an empty text input, an empty span and the following code:

```
$('input').on('input', function(){
    $('span').text(this.value);
});
```

When I type in the input the same text appears in the span. But when I go to another page in the same browser tab and then go back again, the input field is still filled in, but now the span is empty.

How can I make it so that when you go back to the page the span keeps the value of the input?

Thanks!

Edit:
I think I've found the solution.

```
$('input').on('input', function(){
    $('span').text(this.value);
}).not(function(){
    return this.value == '';
}).trigger('input');
```

Comment: the span will only be updated on `input` event. Trigger it manually once the page loads

Comment: `$(function() { $('span').text($('input').val()); });`

Comment: The `not()` method call seems to be doing nothing for you.

Answer (score 6):

The behavior you are experiencing is normal if you are returning to the page by hitting the "back" button or browsing from your local hard drive  - - you are seeing the cached version of the page in that case. Form fields can cache their values, but a `span` doesn't have a "value" per se, it has content and that content isn't cached.

If you were to return to the page by clicking a link or typing an address (things that cause an HTTP request), the text field will not show the last value from the previous time, it will show its default value.

In addition to the code you already have, you just need a script that fires off as soon as the page is ready that resets the `span` to the value of the `input`.

```
// You must already have a document.ready event handler, so just add to that:
$(function(){

  // This will restore the span's content to the value of the textbox
  $('span').text($('input').val());

  // This is your original code that wires up the textbox to a click
  // event handler
  $('input').on('input', function(){
    $('span').text(this.value);
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks. Does it have to be a separate function or could I chain it somehow?

Comment: You could use `on('input change'...` then chain a `trigger('change')` after the event handler.

Comment: Hmm I don't know why but that doesn't seem to work. Calling trigger directly from the console works but it doesn't do it when going back to the page.

Comment: I don't know why that suggestion would work since neither the `input` or `change` events fire upon page load, which is when you need to put the input value back into the span.

Comment: Wouldn't it call trigger() after attaching the handler?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you, but if you call trigger after attaching the document ready handler, how does that help you? And, if you call trigger after attaching the `input` and `change` events, how would it help you then? `.trigger()` is meant to cause all event handlers attached to an element to be fired immediately. That's not what you need here. You need some activity when there is input in the `input` field and you need activity at a completely different point in time, when the page loads. I'm just not following the logic here.

Comment: Well the event is attached when the page loads right? So if you could trigger it once right after it's attached that would work?

Comment: Turns out it did work. I've added the solution at the top.

Comment: @J.Doe Yeah, but where are you writing that code block in the first place? Inside of document.ready (which you already have). So, why not just add the one line I've suggested in the event handler you already have instead of writing a jumbled chain of methods? I'm not even sure what the `not()` method call is buying you. See my updated answer for the complete code solution which is so much simpler than your chain.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to bind window.popstate();

```
$(window).on("popstate", function (e) {
        //code to refill the span goes here.
});
```

I use it to deserialize a potentially changed querystring, but you could likely use it here to the same effect.